# content.script access file resource always error with net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT, disabled Adblock

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm migrating V2 to V3, but encountered some strange problems.
When extension has loaded, i fetching the resource, it will has a error: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT. but it's no problem when i do it without loaded extension.
like this:

[without loaded extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21MIX.jpg)

[with loaded extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyUd4.png)

Extension launch up with a error:

```
GET chrome-extension://hbdmkhahfinoeomfcllpnpkcblpaofeh/css/style.css net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

'web_accessible_resources' in content.js

```js
var css1 = doc.createElement("link");
css1.href = chrome.runtime.getURL("css/style.css");
css1.type = "text/css";
css1.rel = "stylesheet";
doc.head.appendChild(css1);
```

code in manifest.json

```
 "web_accessible_resources" : [{
   "resources": [ "css/*", "content/*" ],
   "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
 }],
```

Converting the txt file to html is the main responsibility of this extension.

I have disabled Adblock Plus, and try to fix this problem pass a whole day, I really don't know what happened in this condition and how to fix it.

Comment: To clarify, do you mean that AdBlock causes the error? Sounds like a bug in AdBlock then. As a workaround you can add a `style` element and set the css as its `textContent`.

Comment: AdBlock dont't cause the error. We found that the operation of link css file will has this error when open a local file. If we open a http/https file,  the error dont' happen. allthough we have changed to use service work to read the file for missing this error, and it's works fine now, but i think that link css file should't  cause error, and this way is fine in v2, only error in v3.

Comment: It's a bug in ManifestV3: https://crbug.com/1219825.

Comment: thx for your help 